# Teamcity Unmet requirements MSBuildTools17

Tags: teamcity

I have an incompatible configurations on one of my builds. I don't khow to solve this, as MSBuild Tools 17 exist on my machine.

> Unmet requirements: Exists=>MSBuildTools17.0_.+_Path exists

I have Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 instaled on my server.

Running

> dotnet msbuild

will show the msbuild version

> MSBuild version 17.5.0-preview-23061-01+040e2a90e for .NET

This is my build step configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the path to msbuild tools 17 to C:\BuildAgent\conf\buildAgent.properties

> MSBuildTools17.0_x86_Path=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin

> MSBuildTools17.0_x64_Path=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64